# Android Widget change resizeMode at runtime

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

Is it possible to change resizeMode of widget to "none" at runtime? This is to handle free/premium version of an app. For example something like this in widget configure or even at onAppWidgetOptionsChanged:

```
widgetInfo.resizeMode = AppWidgetProviderInfo.RESIZE_NONE;
```

Right now the above does not seem to make any changes. Or is it possible to restrict the size change at onAppWidgetOptionsChanged and let the user know it cannot be done and change the size back to 1x1?

Answer (score 0):

You can get your solution from this [Make all widgets resizable](https://gitorious.org/primerunner/packages_apps_launcher2/commit/80db26f)

and more about them read [AppWidgetProviderInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProviderInfo.html)

Best of luck!